# returning number of string.find() in C++

Tags: c++

in python when a character is not in a string '-1' is returned:

```
a = "hello"
a.find("a")
```

result :     `-1`

but in C++ it returns a strange number!!!:

```
string a;
a = "hello";
a.find("a");
```

result :     `4294967295`

what is it???is it equal for all characters in all strings???
and how can i say while an especial string is not in a text do some work??

I know it in python but not in C++...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find()` method will be return the `string::npos` if it doesn't find the special string.
So you should always use the following statement to check the `find()` result:

```
string::size_type index = str.find("value");
if (string::npos != index)
{
   // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It returns `std::string::npos`, when characted is not founded in `string`. `std::string::npos` is defined by standard like

```
static const size_type npos = -1;
```

Answer (score 4):

it is `string::npos`. You should use the following to decide whether you can find a specific string in given string:

```
  size_t foundIndex = a.find("a");
  if ( foundIndex != string::npos)
  {
       cout << "found" <<endl;
  }
```

Comment: @DrewDormann thanks. I meant unsigned int, but better to use size_t I agree.